# Возвращаемые значения в функциях Javascript

Tags: javascript

Имеется код

```
function get(s){
    someobject.somefunc(arg1, {arg2:arg3}, function(r){
        // code
        // code
        return response;
    });
};
retVal = get(s);
```

Как сделать чтобы в retVal передавалось значение которое возвращает return response;

Был такой вариант как

```
someobject = {
    somefunc:function(arg1,obj,func){
        // code
        // code
        return func(r);
    }
}
function get(s){
ret = someobject.somefunc(arg1, {arg2:arg3}, function(r){
       // code 
       // code
        return response;
     });
return ret;
}
retVal = get(s);
```

Но это не сработало. Подскажите как правильно реализовать это. Или ссылку где это подробно описывается. Google не в счет

Comment: Да вроде второй вариант должен сработать!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это неправильное желание :) Если что-то выполняется асинхронно, оно так и должно работать. Например, если someobject делает ajax-запрос, то нельзя затормаживать браузер до тех пор, пока запрос не выполнится. Нужно ждать, пока не выполнится колбек, и только потом продолжать.

В первом примере есть проблема -- колбек не может вернуть значение, просто некуда его возвращать. Я бы сделал так:

```
var retVal ;
var retValReady = false ;
function get(s){
    someobject.somefunc(arg1, {arg2:arg3}, function(r){
        // code
        // code
        retVal = response;
        retValReady = true; //теперь retVal готова к использованию
    });
};
get(s);
```

Но, если идет какая-то последовательность действий, в ходе которой идет обработка retval, эту последовательность нужно разбить на две части

```
var retVal ;
function stageOne() {
//  какой-то код

  function get(s){
    someobject.somefunc(arg1, {arg2:arg3}, function(r){
        // code
        // code
        retVal = response;
        stageTwo();
    });
  };
  get(s);
}

function stageTwo() {
  // здесь уже можно работать с retVal
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Первый вариант оказался более подходящим у меня:)

Answer (score 0):

По вашему первому примеру:

```
function get(s){
    var f = function(r){
        // code
        // code
        return response;
    }
    someobject.somefunc(arg1, {arg2:arg3}, f);
    return f(r);
}
```

В вашем же варианте, в первом случае, функция `get` никогда и ничего не возвратит. Во втором случае - только ссылку на функцию `someobject.somefunc`. Тут нетрудно догадаться, что эта ваша функция `someobject.somefunc`, приводит сама в исполнение ту функцию, которую передаете третьим аргументом и делает то, что ей надо. Если же `someobject.somefunc` не возвращает ничего, то сделайте чтобы она возвращала нужное вам значение.

---

Во втором случае, надо было так примерно:

```
return someobject.somefunc(arg1, {arg2:arg3}, function(r){
    // code 
    // code
    return response;
});
```

Comment: Разве? В вашем примере функция f вызывается два раза (один раз явно (с неинициализированным параметром r) и один раз как колбек). Это не то, наверное

Comment: @beardog, Вас не до конца понял. Но тут же вопрос стоит, как же сделать так, чтобы функция get возвращала response. Но и еще, как я понял, зачем-то вызывала ф-ю "someobject.somefunc". Да, некрасиво, но тут другого варианта не видел. Я ж не знаю что там ф-я "someobject.somefunc" должна выполнять. Вот и получается, что пришлось ф-ю f исполнять два раза.